# Issue when trying to use custom list button

Tags: apex, list-button, visuaforce

i am trying to create a custom object list button but i'm getting an issue "unknown constructor 'sendemailctlr.sendemailctlr()' Markup"

visualforce page

```
<apex:page standardController="Logistic_Contacts__c" controller="SendEmailCtlr" recordSetVar="Logistic_Contact" action="{!sendEmailToCustomer}">

<apex:form >
<apex:pageblock >
  <apex:pageMessages id="showmsg"></apex:pageMessages>
      <!--<apex:commandButton value="Back" action="{!Cancel}" style="width:90px"/>-->
  </apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

apex class

```
public with sharing class SendEmailCtlr {

private Id SLTcontactid;
Public  Logistic_Contacts__c SLTContact;
public SendEmailCtlr(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    SLTcontactid = controller.getId();
    SLTContact=[Select Id, Email_Template_ID__c From Logistic_Contacts__c Where Id=:SLTcontactid]; // change to SLT CONTACT QUERY
}

public PageReference sendEmailToCustomer(){
    String contactId =SLTContact.Logistic_Contact__c;
    Id emailTemplateId=SLTContact.Email_Template_ID__c;
    String SLTCid = SLTContact.id;
    String contactEmail=SLTContact.Logistics_Contact_Email__c;  //EMAIL THAT IT WILL GO TO
    // String emailtemp =System.Label.EmailTemplateID;

    PageReference sendToEmailPage;
         sendToEmailPage = new PageReference('/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p2_lkid=' + contactId + '&p3_lkid=' + SLTCid + '&p24='+ contactEmail +'&retURL='+SLTCid+'&rtype=003&template_id=' + emailTemplateId); 

    return sendToEmailPage;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your controller class is written as a controller extension, which uses a constructor along the lines of

```
public SendEmailCtlr(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
```

That seems to be correct, but your Visualforce page is referencing it as if it were a standard controller, with a `controller=` attribute. Standard controllers use a constructor with no parameters:

```
public SendEmailCtlr() {
```

That's why you're getting an "unknown constructor" error. Just change `controller=` to `extensions=` and Salesforce will find the "right" constructor.

Additionally, your Visualforce page is declared with a `recordSetVar` attribute, which implies that you are using a `StandardSetController`. If you intend to use a set controller, you can change your extension's constructor to

```
public SendEmailCtlr(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
```

Comment: Hey, i'm now getting sendemailctlr.sendemailctlr(apexPages.standardsetcontroller.controller)' Markup

Comment: See updated answer - you'll need to change your constructor signature to reflect your use of a set controller. Note that `StandardSetController` does not have a `getId()` method, so you'll get another error there.

Comment: Brilliant that worked, final question! SLTcontactid = controller.getId(); is no longer working so i'm trying to figure out how to bring through the id still?

Comment: Set controllers store sets of objects, so they don't have a single Id. Since you're only selecting a single contact, it's not clear to me whether you need to change to using a standard controller, or alter your query - it's a design-level issue.

Comment: So i want to send an email to all the ticked rows from the list view, i originally didn't have the recordsetvar part but i couldn't see the visualforce page option when creating the button as a list view, if that makes sense?

Comment: Then you must use a StandardSetController. You can access its contents with [methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardSetController_methods.htm) like `getSelected()`.

Comment: @ClevelandDan plese avoid follo wup questions in comments, instead, open a new post with your new/related question. Thanks